# Wait for user to respond to request for addressbook access in iOS?

Tags: ios, permissions, dialog, authorization

I would like my app to only ask the user for permission to access the Contacts addressbook until the user access the proper function in my app.  I really don't want to request permission when the app loads.

As a result I've used the following code:

```
- (IBAction)importClientsButtonPressed:(id)sender {
// request access to Contacts address book
CFErrorRef addyError = NULL;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &addyError);
if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef addyError) {
    });
}

if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    _importContactsActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Import Client from Contacts"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Primary Contact", @"Secondary Contact", nil];
    _importContactsActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;

    [_importContactsActionSheet showFromRect:self.importClientsButton.frame inView:self.importClientsButton.superview animated:YES];
} else {
    // the user has previously denied access - send alert to user to allow access in Settings app
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Privacy Settings"
                                                    message:@"This app does not have access to your contacts.  You can enable access in Privacy Settings."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

}

However, the permission dialog does not halt the app and wait for a response...the code following the request continues to run.  As a result I get a whack of messages popping up out of order.

Is there any way to have the whole app halt until a response comes back from the permission request dialog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above also you have this:

```
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef addyError)  {
    if(granted) {
        //Put here your code
    }
});
```

so finally i would write the code in this way:

```
- (IBAction)importClientsButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    // request access to Contacts address book
    CFErrorRef addyError = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &addyError);
    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef addyError)  {
            if(granted) {
                [weakSelf openImportContact];
            }
        });
    } else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        [weakSelf openImportContact];
    } else {
        // the user has previously denied access - send alert to user to allow access in Settings app
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Privacy Settings"
                                                        message:@"This app does not have access to your contacts.  You can enable access in Privacy Settings."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}


- (void)openImportContact {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _importContactsActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Import Client from Contacts"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Primary Contact", @"Secondary Contact", nil];
        _importContactsActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;

        [_importContactsActionSheet showFromRect:self.importClientsButton.frame inView:self.importClientsButton.superview animated:YES];
    });
}
```

Comment: But then I have to duplicate a bunch of it...once for if it's the first time and they've just now granted access (like your suggestion above) and then once if access was granted previously and this dialog isn't called.  Right?

Comment: and don't forget to close the address book at the end ;)

Comment: It's really close to working!  However, the openImportContact method dies with the following error, only if it's the first time and the user just granted permission:  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTask:] may only be called from the main thread.'`  I think because of the threading.

Comment: no problem see now the code. The problem was that your code change the UI and so need to be executed in the main thread. But, on the first time the user authorize the app and enter in a block executed in another thread. Now i added a dispatch_async block that assure you to execute the code in the main thread ;)

Comment: Grazzie Matteo!  It works great now!  And I've learned a lot from this!